# Is there a way to remove contiguous vowels with an _ (underline)?

Tags: python

I'm solving this problem where I have to remove 3 contiguous vowel characters.

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
```

For example:

```
input: 'happpyyyy Biiiirthdayyyyaaaa'
output:'happpyyyy B_irthdayyyy_a'
```

explanation: i & a are vowel chars and positioned contiguously. There are four occurrences of both i & a. but only three i & a will be removed.

code:

```
import re
def replaceV(strng):
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    for i in strng:
        if strng.count(i) >= 3 and i in vowels:
            strng = strng.replace(i, '_')
    print(strng)
    remove_duplicates = re.sub(r'_+','_',strng)
    return remove_duplicates
            
print(replaceV('happpyyyy Biiiirthdayyyyaaaaa'))
```

The problem is it's removing all vowel chars. but it should remove only 3 contiguous vowel chars.

Can I get help with this?

I tried using replace(i, '_',3) but that is only removing first 3 occurrences, so that is no use.

Comment: ohh ya! my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with regex.

`r'([aeiou])\1{2}'`

1. `([aeiou])` creates a group to capture vowels. It's the first group so, it is referenced with `\1`
2. `\1{2}` check if group 1 result repeats 2 more times

```
import re
from   functools import partial

#use partial to construct the known parts of sub
#basically we are just priming sub so the only data
#it needs is the input
vwl = partial(re.compile(r'([aeiou])\1{2}').sub, '_')

in_ = 'happpyyyy Biiiirthdayyyyaaaa'

print(vwl(in_)) #happpyyyy B_irthdayyyy_a
```

note: `compile` is run before `sub` so the expression will only be compiled 1 time. This is more efficient than compiling the expression every time the `sub` function is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def replaceV(strng):
    # Match a vowel and 2 more of the same vowel (3 total)
    return re.sub(r'([aeiou])\1{2}', '_', strng)
            
print(replaceV('happpyyyy Biiiirthdayyyyaaaaa'))
```

Output:

```
happpyyyy B_irthdayyyy_aa
```